# Output variable in Javascript alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have built this Javascript part.

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'button', function(g) {
        var spieler_ID = $(this).val();

        $.get('/spieler-update?spielerID=' + spieler_ID, function(data){
            var output = data;
            alert(output);
        });
    });
```

And this is my web route

```
Route::get('/spieler-update', 'SpielerController@getSpielerInfo');
```

Which brings me to this Controller function

```
public function getSpielerInfo(){
                $spielerID = Input::get('spieler_ID');
                return Response($spielerID);
        }
```

Now, I want only to alert the variable output which is 1, 2 or 3 in the first java script part above -> alert. But at the moment the alert is empty. Why?

Comment: Use `console.log` instead. It can show you exactly what the "empty" is.

Comment: console.log(output)? directly under var output = data;?

Comment: Yes, then open your browser's developer console with F12 to see the result.

Comment: javascript console in chrome?

Comment: The Variable is empty

Comment: Yes. Also, could you edit your question to include what technology you're using for that server side code?

Comment: @HansMuff, then go to the network-tab in the dev tools and check the request to and the response from the server.

Comment: I see the link with the correct spielerID. I think the problem is Input to var. There I don't have to information from spielerID. How to get the variable correctly?

Comment: @HansMuff and as a sidenote, do yourself a favor and start being consistent and use just english expressions/names to name the stuff in your code. *(nicht son'n kauderwelsch wie `SpielerController@getSpielerInfo`)* Every single one you'll ever ask for help regarding your code will be grateful about that. It helps understanding your intentions and the structure of your code and data. Especially people who don't speak german; but even for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller function you should return your data as json

```
return response()->json($spielerID);
```